# Application stop working after clicking on one of drawer menus

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-drawer

I'm learning how to use drawer to change fragments in different menus but when I clicked on menus with the script it's "Unfortunately, DrawerTest2 has stopped"

Can someone take a look at my code to see what I did wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package th.ac.sd.drawertest2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            SMSFragment smsFragment = new SMSFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_sms, smsFragment, smsFragment.getTag()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)            {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**SMSFragment.java**

```
package th.ac.sd.drawertest2;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SMSFragment extends Fragment {


    public SMSFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sm, container, false);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="th.ac.sd.drawertest2.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_sm.xml** (The fragment that I wanted to replace content_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="th.ac.sd.drawertest2.SMSFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/layout_sms" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error Log** (From the start and until app's crashes)

```
01-11 23:51:52.017 1065-1065/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-11 23:51:52.073 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/th.ac.sd.drawertest2-1/lib/x86
01-11 23:51:52.088 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is th.ac.sd.drawertest2, real application class is null.

                                                                [ 01-11 23:51:52.124  1605: 1626 D/         ]
                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9c53bd40, tid 1626
01-11 23:51:53.149 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/th.ac.sd.drawertest2-1/lib/x86
01-11 23:51:53.276 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-11 23:51:53.339 1065-1107/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                    [ 01-11 23:51:53.342  1065: 1065 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa23b180, tid 1065


                                                                    [ 01-11 23:51:53.344  1065: 1065 W/         ]
                                                                    Process pipe failed

                                                                    [ 01-11 23:51:53.383  1065: 1107 D/         ]
                                                                    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa23b3c0, tid 1107
01-11 23:51:53.385 1065-1107/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-11 23:51:53.468 1065-1107/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 E/EGL_emulation: tid 1107: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-11 23:51:53.468 1065-1107/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaaabfbc0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
01-11 23:52:04.548 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0c0077 (th.ac.sd.drawertest2:id/layout_sms) for fragment SMSFragment{4b506d #0 id=0x7f0c0077}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity 575a3e1 State:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:   Active Fragments in 3e0a4a2:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     #0: SMSFragment{4b506d #0 id=0x7f0c0077}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0c0077 mContainerId=#7f0c0077 mTag=null
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mState=1 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{3e0a4a2 in HostCallbacks{1ba533}}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@1ba533
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:   Added Fragments:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     #0: SMSFragment{4b506d #0 id=0x7f0c0077}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@1ba533
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@1ba533
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{8d10f0 V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,2560}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{d98669 V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,2392}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{1c868ee G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203a9 android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{861618f V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,2392}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{ca4c1c V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,2392 #7f0c0055 app:id/action_bar_root}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat{2fb2025 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0c0056 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{a5625fa V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,2392 #1020002 android:id/content}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:               android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{f9c87ab VFED.... ... 0,0-1440,2392 #7f0c0069 app:id/drawer_layout}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout{3e0e08 V.ED.... ... 0,0-1440,2392}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout{4e299a1 V.E..... ... 0,84-1440,280}
01-11 23:52:05.428 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{2d0a7c6 V.E..... ... 0,0-1440,196 #7f0c006b app:id/toolbar}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.TextView{f19f387 V.ED.... ... 210,51-609,144}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.ImageButton{7aa02b4 VFED..C. ... 0,0-196,196}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{b6e2edd V.E..... ... 1300,0-1440,196}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{c1f7a52 VFED..C. ... 0,14-140,182}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.RelativeLayout{e184123 V.E..... ... 0,280-1440,2392 #7f0c006d app:id/content_main}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{83e9620 V.ED.... ... 56,56-321,122}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton{123dbd9 VFED..C. ... 1188,2140-1384,2336 #7f0c006c app:id/fab}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.design.widget.NavigationView{c16e99e V.E..... ... 0,0-980,2392 #7f0c006a app:id/nav_view}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView{f23cc7f VFED.V.. F.. 0,0-980,2392 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_navigation_view}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.LinearLayout{3c6f44c V.E..... ... 0,0-980,588 #7f0c0072 app:id/navigation_header_container}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{8ed5c95 V.E..... ... 0,0-980,560}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{f8401aa V.ED.... ... 56,92-224,316 #7f0c0078 app:id/imageView}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{732b19b V.ED.... ... 56,316-924,438}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b950938 V.ED.... ... 56,438-693,504 #7f0c0079 app:id/textView}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{942d11 VFED..C. ... 0,588-980,756}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{f88e76 V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{a80cc77 V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{22d80e4 VFED..C. ... 0,756-980,924}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{efd894d V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{571c02 V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{b2bb913 VFED..C. ... 0,924-980,1092}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{bb3c750 V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{a266d49 V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{71ef64e VFED..C. ... 0,1092-980,1260}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{58ed36f V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{916087c V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.FrameLayout{df9505 V.E..... ... 0,1260-980,1292}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.view.View{578295a V.ED.... ... 0,28-980,32}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{65f378b V.ED.... ... 0,1292-980,1460}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{9f93068 VFED..C. ... 0,1460-980,1628}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{4497c81 V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{3ff8126 V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{687c167 VFED..C. ... 0,1628-980,1796}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{164eb14 V.ED.... ... 56,0-924,168 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.FrameLayout{d105fbd V.E..... ... 924,0-924,168 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/FragmentManager:       android.view.View{65289b2 V.ED.... ... 0,2392-1440,2560 #1020030 android:id/navigationBarBackground}
01-11 23:52:05.429 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                    --------- beginning of crash
01-11 23:52:05.430 1065-1065/th.ac.sd.drawertest2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: th.ac.sd.drawertest2, PID: 1065
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0077 (th.ac.sd.drawertest2:id/layout_sms) for fragment SMSFragment{4b506d #0 id=0x7f0c0077}
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Someone have an idea what's I did wrong? This is my very first application so I may did someting wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add app_bar_main layout to verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not replace your `content_main` layout with another. You want your `content_main` to have a fragment container like this:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

in your code you should use this code snippet to put your fragments into the `FrameLayout`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                           .commit();
```

In your case copy your `content_main` layout to another file say `first_fragmet.xml`. Create another fragment for it and inflate it like you did in `SMSFragment`.
On your activity's `onCreate()` method use the above code to place the first fragment. For example

```
fragment = new FirstFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
                           .commit();
```

When you wish to replace the current view with your `SMSFragment` just use the same code above but with `fragment` as your `SMSFragment` object. 
See [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)  for more information.